# Solution for PWA app to work offline if user deletes phone or browser cache

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

Is there a workaround for PWA app to work offline if user deletes phone or browser cache?

I have created and tested app offline, it works as expected. But if I delete cache from storage on my phone or clear browsing cache, app displays fallback page (without css).

Comment: well, since the offline functionality depends on the cache, deleting the cache will obviously effect offline functionality ...

Comment: The workaround is that the user starts over and possibly reinstalls your PWA. The control is the user's to delete whatever they want. You have no way to permanently store anything on their device. Realistically it will probably NEVER happen with real users. It COULD and a boss may want you to program for that. But if it does, it's somebody playing around.